# GLSL bitwise vec4 to float copy

Tags: copy, glsl, bit

(How) is it possible to do a bitwise copy of a vec4(32bit) into a float(32bit) bitwise ?

Already tried:
[Vec4ToFloat and Back](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7059962/how-do-i-convert-a-vec4-rgba-value-to-a-float)
[Vec4ToFloat and Back](http://www.ozone3d.net/blogs/lab/20080604/glsl-float-to-rgba8-encoder/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A vec4 is *usually* 128 bits (4x32-bit float), so packing it into a single float is problematic.

Perhaps you mean packing an arbitrary 32-bit value into a float?  You can use the builtin `intBitsToFloat` to copy 32 bits from an `int` to a `float` in a bitwise manner.  However, the resulting float value might be a Nan of some type, in which case converting it back to an int with `floatBitsToInt` might not give you the same result.

**edit**

From your comment, you seem to confusing pixel formats in buffers with numeric formats in the shader.  Whenever you read a pixel from a buffer or texture, it will be converted from the pixel format to a numeric format, depending on *how* you read the pixel.  If you've done a normal `texture` lookup on a `sampler` of some kind bound to a RGBA texture, then each channel of the texure will have been unpacked into a 32-bit float in the range 0.0..1.0.  You can easily pack it back into a 32-bit uint with `packUnorm4x8`, and then convert that 32-bit uint to a float with `intBitsToFloat` (which might have the above noted problem with Nan on the second step).  Or you can just read it as a 32-bit int or float in the first place by using the appropriate texel type when you set up the sampler (which will affect interpolation, but you probably don't want interpolation at all, depending on what you are trying to do).

Comment: But the Pixel Value of a Image is 32bits RGBA exactly, how can I convert this value to a Float bit by Bit ?